# OpenSplice DDS open source implementation support - Database Transaction Processing?

Tags: data-distribution-service

I want to use OpenSplice DDS for "Messaging" and  "Database Transaction Processing" functionalities.

Can you please help to know if OpenSplice DDS open source implementation supports - "Database Transaction Processing" or not?

Can anyone share the experience with OpenSplice DDS?

Comment: What do you mean by "Database Transaction Processing" in the context of DDS? OpenSplice is not a database technology, are you maybe looking to integrate it with an RDBMS? Also, to "share the experience with OpenSplice DDS" is a pretty open-ended task. Could you be more specific in your question please? Maybe add some information about your use case and how you are thinking of using DDS.

Comment: I need to integrate OpenSplice with RDBMS. Does OpenSlice provide Interfaces /APIs to work with RDBMS.

Comment: I need to integrate OpenSplice with RDBMS. Does OpenSlice provide Interfaces /APIs to work with RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSplice DDS Community Edition (the "open source" version) does not feature any out-of-the-box integration with a DBMS. Its commercial version does provide an optional service called DBMSConnect that might do what you are looking for. You did not describe in detail what you are trying to achieve, so it is hard to assess.

As far as I know, there is no on-line documentation available on DBMSConnect for you to check out whether it would do what you are looking for. However, the DDS implementation from RTI has a similar feature, also commercially available only, called Real-Time Connect. Full documentation for that is available on-line via the [Real-Time Connect User's Manual](http://community.rti.com/rti-doc/500/RTI_Real-Time_Connect_5.0.0/docs/RTI_RTC_UsersManual.pdf). There are more links on Real-Time Connect on their [Community Portal Documentation](http://community.rti.com/content/page/documentation) page. That might help you in assessing whether it meets your needs.